# How to represent powers in a select option?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple select object like :

```
<select id = "mySelect" >
<option>First</option>
<option>Second</option>
</select>
```

Now, what if I want to write First<sup>2</sup> in an option?

If I write `First <sup>2</sup>` Then it does not works and the 2 printed like any normal 2. So, how to represent powers in a select option? Also, If I add an option using JavaScript:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "First" + "<sup>2</sup>";
     mySelect.add(option);
```

Then also, how to represent powers?

Comment: There is no way, as an alternative, you can make a hidden select item and make a select box yourself, some extra markup and JS of course, then on click event of your own-built select options, change the real select's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, formatting inside `<option>` tags is not supported. Your best solution would be to write it out as `First^2`, which is the common way of writing powers in a linear way.